# Fallo de índice en una entidad débil MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy a crear una entidad débil MySQL llamada ubicaciones_plantas, que depende de otra llamada departamentos. La en cuestión tiene esta estructura en SQL:

```
- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bd`.`ubicaciones_plantas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bd`.`ubicaciones_plantas` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventario_aixina`.`ubicaciones_plantas` (
  `iddepartamento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `idubicacion` INT NOT NULL,
  `abreviacion_ubicacion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion_ubicacion` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iddepartamento`, `idubicacion`)
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `bd`.`ubicaciones_plantas`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ubicacion_departamento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`iddepartamento`)
    REFERENCES `bd`.`ubicaciones_plantas` (`iddepartamento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

La tabla de departamentos, de esta otra forma:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `bd`.`departamentos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bd`.`departamentos` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bd`.`departamentos` (
  `iddepartamentos` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_departamento` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `sede_departamento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iddepartamentos`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_departamento_sede`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sede_departamento`)
    REFERENCES `bd`.`sedes` (`idsedes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_departamento_sede_idx` ON `bd`.`departamentos` (`sede_departamento` ASC) VISIBLE;
```

Al arrancar en MySQL Workbench, salta este error de indexación:

[image: Falta Constraint e indexación]

Toda SQL la he generado desde el EER Model, y al tener el fallo anterior, la constraint la puse a mano y vuelve al mismo punto.

Qué tengo que modificar en la entidad débil para que pueda continuar creando el resto de tablas?

Muchas gracias por anticipado! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que una clave ajena debe estar referenciada a un campo, al menos, indexado. Añade este índice y ya no te dará el error que comentas:

```
ALTER TABLE ubicaciones_plantas ADD INDEX(iddepartamento);
```

Comment: Muy buena aclaración, se ha arreglado parte del script. Muchas gracias.